# Xcode Swift: Cannot close popup Image

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I created a `ViewController` that displays three images and other info via JSON parsing through three separate `UIImageViews`. When you click any of the images, it takes you to another `ViewController` that pop-ups a `UIScrollView` in the background, one `UIImageView` which is linked to all three images and a `Button` that would close the pop-up `ViewController` and bring it back to the previous one. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkAah.jpg). The problem I am having is that I added this code:

```
func removeZoom()
    {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)
            self.view.alpha = 0.0;
            }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
                if (finished)
                {
                    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
                }
        });
    }

    @IBAction func closeZoom(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }
```

And when I try to click on the close button, nothing happens. Don't know what I am missing. Any guidance would be helpful.

Here i'll put the code for both controllers:

**JnsDetail.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class JnsDetail: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tituloLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var marcaLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var colorLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var tipoLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var refLabel : UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var imageView : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var imageView2 : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var imageView3 : UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet var backbutton : UIButton!

    var jsonextrct : JsonExtrct!

    var photos : [String]!

    var transitionOperator = TransitionOperator()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //titulo = jsonextrct.titulo

        tituloLabel.font = UIFont(name: mTheme.fontName, size: 21)
        tituloLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        tituloLabel.text = jsonextrct.titulo

        //marca = jsonextrct.marca

        marcaLabel.font = UIFont(name: mTheme.fontName, size: 21)
        marcaLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        marcaLabel.text = jsonextrct.marca

        //color = jsonextrct.color

        colorLabel.font = UIFont(name: mTheme.fontName, size: 21)
        colorLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        colorLabel.text = jsonextrct.color

        //tipo = jsonextrct.tipo

        tipoLabel.font = UIFont(name: mTheme.fontName, size: 21)
        tipoLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        tipoLabel.text = jsonextrct.tipo

        //ref = jsonextrct.ref

        refLabel.font = UIFont(name: mTheme.fontName, size: 21)
        refLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        refLabel.text = "\(jsonextrct.ref)"

        if let imageData = jsonextrct.imageData {
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        }else{
            Utils.asyncLoadJsonImage(jsonextrct, imageView: imageView)
        }
        //topImageViewHeightConstraint.constant = 240

        imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

        if let imageData2 = jsonextrct.imageData2 {
            imageView2.image = UIImage(data: imageData2)
        }else{
            Utils.asyncLoadJsonImage(jsonextrct, imageView2: imageView2)
        }

        imageView2.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        imageView2.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

        if let imageData3 = jsonextrct.imageData3 {
            imageView3.image = UIImage(data: imageData3)
        }else{
            Utils.asyncLoadJsonImage(jsonextrct, imageView3: imageView3)
        }

        imageView3.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        imageView3.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

        var tapGestureZoom = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "zoomJns:")
        tapGestureZoom.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGestureZoom.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureZoom)

        var tapGestureZoom2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "zoomJns2:")
        tapGestureZoom2.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGestureZoom2.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        imageView2.userInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView2.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureZoom2)

        var tapGestureZoom3 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "zoomJns3:")
        tapGestureZoom3.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGestureZoom3.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        imageView3.userInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView3.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureZoom3)

    }

    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.Default
    }

    func backTapped(sender: AnyObject?){
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func zoomJns(sender: AnyObject?){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("JnsZoomController") as! JnsZoomController
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom
        controller.transitioningDelegate = transitionOperator
        controller.jsonextrct = jsonextrct

        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func zoomJns2(sender: AnyObject?){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("JnsZoomController") as! JnsZoomController
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom
        controller.transitioningDelegate = transitionOperator
        controller.jsonextrct = jsonextrct

        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func zoomJns3(sender: AnyObject?){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("JnsZoomController") as! JnsZoomController
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom
        controller.transitioningDelegate = transitionOperator
        controller.jsonextrct = jsonextrct

        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

**JnsZoomController.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class JnsZoomController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView : UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var jnsImageView : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var jnsImageView2 : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var jnsImageView3 : UIImageView!

    var jsonextrct : JsonExtrct!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let imageData = jsonextrct.imageData {

            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            jnsImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            //jnsImageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image?.size.width, image?.size.height);
        }

        if let imageData2 = jsonextrct.imageData2 {

            let image2 = UIImage(data: imageData2)
            jnsImageView2.image = UIImage(data: imageData2)
            //jnsImageView2.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image?.size.width, image?.size.height);
        }

        if let imageData3 = jsonextrct.imageData3 {

            let image3 = UIImage(data: imageData3)
            jnsImageView3.image = UIImage(data: imageData3)
            //jnsImageView3.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image?.size.width, image?.size.height);
        }

        scrollView.contentSize = jnsImageView.frame.size
        scrollView.contentSize = jnsImageView2.frame.size
        scrollView.contentSize = jnsImageView3.frame.size

    }

    func removeZoom()
    {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)
            self.view.alpha = 0.0;
            }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
                if (finished)
                {
                    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
                }
        });
    }

    @IBAction func closeZoom(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem as I see it, if you are "popping" to root view controller this means that you must have PUSHED a view controller onto the navigation controller's stack and I don't see you pushing anything onto a navigation stack. Unless of course for some reason Apple decided to kill off Pushing view controllers, but I doubt this is the case. So, there's another problem with what I'm seeing in your code. You are PRESENTING view controllers by just presenting a view controller, I don't see where you are presenting a view controller by using a navigation controller to present the view controller SOOO, if you call

```
     self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

then there's nothing on the stack that the navigation controller is to remove from the stack since you presented the viewcontroller modally over another viewcontroller without presenting the modal in the view controller's navigation controller.

Solution, maybe, but this isn't 100% becuase I don't have your code in front of me.

change this:

```
     self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

to something like this

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(animated: true, completion:nil)
```

I don't do swift so my solution is pseudo code, feel free to add the questions marks and what not that Apple decided has value for some reason.

You could also just change your presentations to this:

```
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Again, the above is psuedo code but I think I place the question mark in just the right spot for so that it does what it's suppose to do

Also, you can refer to this, although Apple doesn't really do a very thoroughly job of telling you how an advanced navigaiton stack works:

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:

Sometimes you will need to have maybe 4-10 navigation controllers running at one time, so make sure you understand how they interact with view controllers and make sure you understand what POPs, PUSHes, and PRESENTs do. And good luck, have a good day.

Comment: I'll check it out and see if there's something we are missing

Comment: Another issue I'm now seeing is possibly this "self.view.removeFromSuperview()" in the animation at the bottom of the view controller, I wouldn't remove anything from the view unless you first POP if off the top of the navigation stack or DISMISS it. By anything I mean a view controller

Comment: For what I see, he's not using that `self.view.removeFromSuperview()` at all, maybe is there as a failed approach, but anyway don't do that :P

Comment: It's right near the bottom, about 10 lines up from the bottom of his post

Comment: It worked! Changed it to `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)` to `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)` and removed some other code from another file and it went well. I also removed the `removeZoom` method. Thanks!

Comment: BOOM, good luck with your app, looks like it's going to be awesome

Comment: Great! mark this as the answer, is more robust than mine :P

Comment: Appreciate it man! There are a couple more things to do but its looking well :) Mind if I can ask you again if I need help?

Comment: Yep, no problem, just ask away, but POST to this web site, not necessarily so I get the rep points but because they get pissed off if we keep talking in the comments.

Comment: @Larcerax Hey man, do you know how to get images in `PageView` open different `NavigationControllers`? If so, I would appreciate your help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056307/using-uipageview-images-to-open-viewcontroller-w-navigationcontroller Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the closeZoom I think you should use only

```
@IBAction func closeZoom(sender: AnyObject) {

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Because you presented that View Controller, that `popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)` is used when you push it

Comment: Thanks! Going to give it a try.