# Using UIPageView images to open ViewController w/ NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I am trying to make three images in a `UIPageView` to open three different `NavigationController`. Here is my layout as of [right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Slfb.jpg). I connected three Custom Segue to each `NavigationController` and under `ContentViewController`, I added the following `@IBAction` method:

```
@IBAction func navJns(sender: AnyObject?){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Nav", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Jeans") as! Jeans
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom

        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func navBlusas(sender: AnyObject?){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Nav", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Blusas") as! Blusas
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom

        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func navLeggings(sender: AnyObject?){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Nav", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Leggings") as! Leggings
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom

        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And under the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
var tapGesturePageView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "navJns:"); self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesturePageView)

        var tapGesturePageView2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "navBlusas:"); self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesturePageView2)

        var tapGesturePageView3 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "navLeggings:"); self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesturePageView3)
```

When I compile and run the app, it shows the three images in the `PageView` but nothing is happening.

Any advice would be helpful!

Here is the rest of the code:

**ContentViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ContentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var pageIndex: Int!
    var imageFile: String!



    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: self.imageFile)

        var tapGesturePageView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "navJns:"); self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesturePageView)

        var tapGesturePageView2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "navBlusas:"); self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesturePageView2)

        var tapGesturePageView3 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "navLeggings:"); self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesturePageView3)

    }

    @IBAction func navJns(sender: AnyObject?){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Nav", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Jeans") as! Jeans
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom

        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func navBlusas(sender: AnyObject?){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Nav", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Blusas") as! Blusas
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom

        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func navLeggings(sender: AnyObject?){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Nav", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Leggings") as! Leggings
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom

        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {


    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
    var pageImages: NSArray!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.pageImages = NSArray(objects: "jeans.png", "blusas.png", "leggings.png")

        self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

        var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController
        var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 60)

        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
        self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> ContentViewController?
    {

if index >= self.pageImages.count
        {
            return nil
        }

        var vc: ContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController

        vc.imageFile = self.pageImages[index] as! String
        vc.pageIndex = index

        return vc


    }


    // MARK: - Page View Controller Data Source

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {

        var vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
        var index = vc.pageIndex as Int


        if (index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil

        }

        index--

        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
        var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

        if (index == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil
        }

        index++

        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
    {
        return 0
    }


}
```

Comment: "but nothing is happening" What do you mean by "nothing"?

Comment: You are adding three tap gesture recognizers to the same image view?

Comment: When I click in the `ImageView` its not giving me any response to open the required `NavigationController` I am selecting. Don't know if my `tapgesture` or `@IBAction` code is incorrect since its not giving me any error in the debug outlet.

Comment: Yes, I am adding three tap gestures to the same imageview

Comment: "Don't know if my tapgesture or @IBAction code is incorrect" But you _do_ know if that code is _running_. Is it?

Comment: "I am adding three tap gestures to the same imageview" And why does that make any sense? You can't do three different things simultaneously.

Comment: So, what suggestion can you recommend?

Comment: i'm looking at this now, let me see what I can come up with

Comment: Okay, so here's a quick question, how does the "contentViewController" get presented?

Comment: nevermind, I'm seeing how you do this now

Comment: @Larcerax It has a storyboard ID and its holding an `UIImageView` which connects to each navigation controllers through a Custom Segue.

Comment: Yep, so if you can verify that right now the methods "navJns", "navBlusas", etc. are intercepting touch events, then I'll know what to look at in addition to what I'm looking at. There's either something wrong with the touch intercepts or something screwy about the way a UIPageViewController manages it's pages when a page wants to PRESENT another UINavigationController on top of it

Comment: Well, all three methods are using the same `ImageView` and under each Custom Segue it has its own identifier and same Segue Class that is called `CustomSeg`

Comment: Yep, look at the answer I'm going to give, this is a hackaround, but not really, because I don't know if there's any other option, just a sec, I'll show you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I asked last night to another user who was helping me and told me that to implement a method which you provide as action ... func ins(){ // create view controller here which I want to push, or if you have a segue in storyboard then call performSegue method.

Comment: Yeah, well this method I'm showing you is a little crazy, but it should work, but no gaurantees

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87193/discussion-between-wlmrlsda-and-larcerax).

Comment: actually, since I know I'll be downvoted by the idiots here who don't understand advanced navigation, I won't post an answer, but here's the deal, the class "ViewController" exposes the entire app to the "pageViewController" becuase of how you declared the UIPageViewController. So, this means that a work around would be that you PRESENT from the "pageViewController" inside the IBOutlets. This is going to involve some intense type casting within the contentViewController. This assumes also that the UIPageViewController can hanle presenting another view controller, and it should be able ...